# How can I know if a non-required RenderSection exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@* Omitted code.. *@
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("Sidebar", required: false)
```

Is there any way to know in the `Omitted code` part if the RenderSection `Sidebar` exists or not?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Sidebar"))
{
    @RenderSection("Sidebar")
}
else
{
    <div>Some default content</div>
}
```